# sql query to get dIvided group

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
  Table - Activity(jobid,duedate,status)
```

status can be either 'Complete' or "NotComplete".

I need a single sql query to get

1. how many jobs are complete
2. how many jobs are not-complete having duedate is greater than current date
3. how many jobs are not-complete having duedate is less than current date

Can anyone please help me with this? Result should have only 3 rows and two columns.

***Edit*** : I am looking for best query, perhaps with any inbuilt function/keyword which performs task in single line query. Not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output?

Comment: What have you tried?  What goes wrong?  What problems are you encountering?

Comment: Please try to put some efforts & then ask for help here, you will get very quick & correct responses.

Comment: @jpw output is like c-2 NcLess-3 NcGreater-5

Comment: @brandon I have tried case,sum using CTE, I got output as well but I am looking for best query, perhaps with any inbuilt function/keyword which performs task in single line query. Not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everyone, Thanks for your reply. I was looking for best query with 2 columns. This is my solution. If anyone have short/good version query, please suggest.

```
    ;with cte as (
select 
    case 
        when stat = 'N' and duedate > GETDATE() then 'NG' 
        when stat = 'N' and duedate < GETDATE() then 'NL' 
        else stat 
    end As S, duedate from activity)
    select S,COUNT(*) from CTE group by (S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT Count(jobid) AS total, 
       'Completed' 
FROM   activity 
GROUP  BY status 
HAVING status = 'Complete' 
UNION 
SELECT Count(jobid) AS total, 
       'Completed Due in past.' 
FROM   activity 
WHERE  duedate >= Getdate() 
GROUP  BY status 
HAVING status = 'Complete' 
UNION 
SELECT Count(jobid) AS total, 
       'Completed Due in past.' 
FROM   activity 
WHERE  duedate < Getdate() 
GROUP  BY status 
HAVING status = 'Complete'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try case :

```
select
  case when status='Complete' then '1'
       when status='NotComplete' and duedate >= getdate() then '2'
  else '3' end,
  count(jobid)
from Activity
group by 
  case when status='Complete' then '1'
       when status='NotComplete' and duedate >= getdate() then '2'
  else '3' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT COUNT(JOBID) Completed Jobs, STATUS
FROM Activity
WHERE STATUS = "Complete"
GROUP BY STATUS
    UNION
SELECT COUNT(JOBID) Completed Jobs, STATUS
FROM Activity
WHERE duedate > GETDATE() AND STATUS = "NotComplete"
GROUP BY STATUS
    UNION
SELECT COUNT(JOBID) Completed Jobs, STATUS
FROM Activity
WHERE duedate < GETDATE() AND STATUS = "NotComplete"
GROUP BY STATUS;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum( case when status = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end ) as completedJobs, 
Sum ( case when status ='NotCompleted' and duedate > getdate() then 1 else 0 end ) as notcompletedinDuedate,
Sum ( case when status ='NotCompleted' and duedate < getdate() then 1 else 0 end ) as notcompletedJobs
From Activity
```